# Expectation of Time Series Process

Tags: probability, statistics, time-series

So I have the following AR(2) process:

$z_t = \delta + \psi_2z_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$

which has the following MA($\infty$) representation:

$\frac{\delta}{1 - \psi_2} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \psi_2^n \epsilon_{t-2n}$

Now I am looking for $E[z_t|z_1, z_2, . . . ,z_{t-2}, z_{t-1}]$

This is where I am kind of confused.

Would it just be $\frac{\delta}{1 - \psi_2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \psi_2^n \epsilon_{t-2n}$

Therefore, the only difference would be the sum begining at $1$ instead of $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the $MA(\infty)$ representation here? If you're conditioning on the previous values, they can be taken out of the conditional expectation. So we have

$$\mathbb{E}[z_t|z_1,\dots,z_{t-1}]=\mathbb{E}[\delta +\psi_2 z_{t-2}+\epsilon_t|z_1,\dots,z_{t-1}] = \delta + \psi_2z_{t-2}+\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t|z_1,\dots,z_{t-1}]$$

You mention the process is AR(2), so presumably the white noise terms are i.i.d. and independent of the history of the process, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t|z_1,\dots,z_{t-1}]=\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t]=0$. So we would have

$$\mathbb{E}[z_t|z_1,\dots,z_{t-1}]= \delta + \psi_2z_{t-2}$$

Comment: Because I’m looking to represent the conditional expectation as an MA process rather than as a AR process

Comment: In that case you can just take the above solution and then rewrite $z_{t-2}$ using its MA representation so that the conditional expectation is in MA form.

Comment: I’m confused on your suggestion. Can you be a tad bit more explicit? Would my solution in the original post not be correct?

Comment: You have the MA$(\infty)$ representation for $z_t$ right? So therefore you also have the $MA(\infty)$ representation for $z_{t-2}$; just replace "$t$" in your original expression with "$t-2$".So substitute this MA($\infty$) representation for $z_{t-2}$ in the solution I gave. If you do this, and simplify, you might arrive at the solution you gave, I'm not sure, but either way doing this will prove your result is correct rather than by intuition.